# Facade in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In OOP, should a *Facade* be an **object** or just a **class**? Which is better?

Most of the examples in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) creates Facade as an object which should be instantiated before use.

```
CarFacade cf = new CarFacade();
cf.start();
```

Can it be designed to be like this instead?

```
CarFacade.start();
```

**UPDATE**

Can a `Facade` facilitate a singleton?

Comment: The argument between an instance (as you call object) and a static class can easily boil down to: Does the class hold the state of something? Does the class represent a single of many? If not, use a static class. If so, use an instance.

Comment: May want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529053/session-facade-vs-singleton-object-design-patterns-in-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A facade

- represents a high level API for a complex subsystem (module).
- reduces client code dependencies.

  This means that your client code only uses the facade and does
  not have a lot of dependencies to classes behind that facade.

It is better to use an instance of an interface, because

- you can replace it for tests. E.g. mock the subsystem the facade represents.
- you can replace it at runtime.

When you use a static methods, your client code is bound to that method implementations at compile-time. This is usually the opposite of the [open/close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

I said **"usually the opposite"**, because there are examples when static methods are used, but the system is still open for extension. E.g.

- [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

  The static load methods only scan the classpath and lookup service implementations. Thus adding classes and `META-INF/services` descriptions to the classpath will add other available services without changing the `ServiceLoader`'s code.
- Spring's `AuthenticationFacade` for example uses a `ThreadLocal` internally. This makes it possible to replace the behavior of the `AuthenticationFacade`. Thus it is open for extension too.

Finally I think it is better to use an instance and interface like I would use for most of the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's two fold. You can use it as a static method. Say for instance in spring security I use AuthenticationFacade to access currently logged in user Principal details like so. `AuthenticationFacade.getName()`

There are other instances, in which mostly people create an instance of Facade and use it. In my opinion neither approach is superior over the other. Rather it depends on your context.

Finally Facade can use `Singleton` pattern to make sure that it creates only one instance and provides a global point of access to it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly subjective. The only reason I am responding is because I reviewed some of my own code and found where I had written a Façade in one application as a singleton and written almost the same Façade in a different application requiring an instance. I'm going to discuss why I chose each of those routes in their respective applications so that I can evaluate if I made the correct choice.

A façade vs the open/close principle is already explained by @Rene Link. In my personal experience, you have to think of it this way: **Does the object hold the state of itself?**

Let's say I have a façade that wraps the Azure Storage API for .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-dotnet)

This facade holds information about how to authenticate against the storage API so that it the client can do something like this:

```
Azure.Authenticate(username, password);
Azure.CreateFile("My New Text File", "\\FILELOCATION");
```

As you can see in this example, I have not created an instance and i'm using static methods, therefore following the singleton pattern. While this makes for code that is more concise, I now have an issue if I need to authenticate to a given path with a different credential than the one already provided, I would have to do something like this:

```
Azure.Authenticate(username, password)
Azure.CreateFile("My New Text File", "\\FILELOCATION");

Azure.Authenticate(username2, password2);
Azure.CreateFile("My Restrictied Text File", "\\RESTRTICTEDFILELOCATION");
```

While this would work, it can be hard to determine why authentication failed when I call `Azure.ReadFile`, as I have no idea what username and password may have been passed into the singleton from thread4 on form2 (which is no where to found) This is a prime example of where you should be using an instance. It would make much more since to do something like this:

```
Using (AzureFacade myAzure = Azure.Authenticate(username, password)) 
{
    Azure.CreateFile("My New Text File", "\\FILELOCATION"); // I will always know the username and password.
}
```

With that said, what happens if the developer needs to create a file in Azure in a method that has no idea what the username and password to Azure may be. A good example of this would be an application that periodically connects to Azure and performs some multi-threaded tasks. In said application, the user setups a connection string to azure and all mulit-threaded tasks are performed using that connection string. Therefore, there is no need to create an instance for each thread (as the state of the object will always be the same) However, in order to maintain thread safety, you don't want to share the same instance across all the threads. This is where a singleton, thread-safe pattern may come into play. (Spring's `AuthenticationFacade` according to @Rene Link) So that I could do something like this (psudocode)

```
Thread[] allTask = // Create 5 threads

Azure.Authenticate(username, password) // Authenticate for all 5 threads.

allTask.start(myfunction)

void myFunction() 
{
    Azure.CreateFile("x");
}
```

Therefore, the choice between an instance of a façade v. a singleton façade is completely dependent on the intended application of the facade, however both can definitely exist.